# Django ModelAdmin not working with custom field method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to write a custom method to ovveride the default viewing of a field in ModelAdmin, a described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/

So this should work:

```
@admin.register(Contract)
class ContractDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "status", "date_end")
    list_filter = ('name','status', "date_end", "headquarters_access_list")
    fields = ("name", "status", "date_start", "date_end", "manager_list", "buyer", "get_document_list_field", "headquarters_access_list")

    @admin.display(empty_value='???')
    def get_document_list_field(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([c.name for c in obj.document_list.all()])
```

Where the model is:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Contract')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Contracts')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                help_text=_('Contract name'),
                                verbose_name=_('contract name'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, 
                                default=ContractStatus.OPEN,
                                choices=ContractStatus.choices(),
                                help_text=_('Status'),
                                verbose_name=_('Status'))
    date_start = models.DateField(editable=True,
                                help_text=_('Start date'),
                                verbose_name=_('Start date'))
    date_end = models.DateField(editable=True,
                                help_text=_('End date'),
                                verbose_name=_('End date'))
    manager_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
                                blank=True,
                                help_text=_('Manager list'),
                                verbose_name=_('Manager list'))
    buyer = models.OneToOneField(CompanyData,  # Committente
                                related_name="buyer",
                                on_delete=models.RESTRICT, 
                                default=None,
                                null=True,
                                auto_created=False,
                                help_text=_('Buyer'),
                                verbose_name=_('buyer'))
    headquarters_access_list = models.ManyToManyField(Headquarters, 
                                blank=True,
                                help_text=_('Headquarters access list'),
                                verbose_name=_('Headquarters access list'))
    contractor_list = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyData, 
                                blank=True,
                                help_text=_('Contractors list'),
                                verbose_name=_('Contractors list'))
    staff_list = models.ManyToManyField(UserData,
                                blank=True,
                                help_text=_('Staff list'),
                                verbose_name=_('Staff list'))
    vehicle_list = models.ManyToManyField(VehicleData,
                                blank=True,
                                help_text=_('Vehicle list'),
                                verbose_name=_('Vehicle list'))
    document_list = models.ManyToManyField(Document,
                                blank=True,
                                help_text=_('Document list'),
                                verbose_name=_('Document list'))
```

When going to the chagne page of the model (/admin/common/contract/1/change/) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 710, in get_form
        return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 563, in modelform_factory
        return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 276, in __new__
        raise FieldError(message)
    
    During handling of the above exception (Unknown field(s) (get_document_list_field) specified for Contract), another exception occurred:
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
        return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1660, in change_view
        return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
        return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1574, in _changeform_view
        ModelForm = self.get_form(
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\myproject-1PRTDUa5-py3.9\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 712, in get_form
        raise FieldError(
    
    Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/common/contract/1/change/
    Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (get_document_list_field) specified for Contract. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ContractDataAdmin.
```

Where is the problem? get_document_list_field is the equivalent of view_birth_date in the official documentation:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'title', 'view_birth_date')

    @admin.display(empty_value='???')
    def view_birth_date(self, obj):
        return obj.birth_date
```

What is a possible way to do the same? I need to customize the view of a certain field while changing.

Comment: You want this field to appear on the change form?

Comment: Hi, Iain. Yes I want this to appear in the change form as a customized list actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a custom "field" that is the result of a method displayed in your form you need to pass it to [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

```
@admin.register(Contract)
class ContractDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "status", "date_end")
    list_filter = ('name','status', "date_end", "headquarters_access_list")
    fields = ("name", "status", "date_start", "date_end", "manager_list", "buyer", "get_document_list_field", "headquarters_access_list")
    readonly_fields = ("get_document_list_field", )

    @admin.display(empty_value='???')
    def get_document_list_field(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([c.name for c in obj.document_list.all()])
```

Comment: This works. Thank you so much Iain. It should be documented in the official Django docs. I will check how to change that.